# 'Component' is defined but never user no-unused-vars React

Tags: javascript, react, jsx, react-dom, eslint

Estou usando o React pela primeira vez e está dando esse erro quando crio um componente e exporto para ser instancionado no index.js

```js
src\index.js
  Line 4:8:  'firstComponent' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in [eslint] 
src\index.js
  Line 4:8:  'firstComponent' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Esse é o código que está no index e no firstComponent:

```js
//FirstComponent.jsx
import React from 'react'

const component = () =>{
    return <h1>component</h1>
}
export default component

//index.js

import React from  'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import firstComponent from './components/firstComponent'


ReactDOM.render(<firstComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Você está importando o arquivo errado, e os componentes em react devem começar com letra maiúscula

```
//FirstComponent.jsx
import React from 'react'

const Component = () =>{
    return <h1>component</h1>
}
export default Component 

//index.js

import React from  'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Component from './components/FirstComponent'


ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('root'))
```